# Is there a better way to do this mysql join?

Tags: mysql, join

Here is the query,

```
$q = $dbc -> prepare("SELECT social.withID, accounts.username 
      FROM social, accounts 
      WHERE social.withID = accounts.id AND social.id = ? AND friendAccept = 1");
$q -> execute(array($user['id']));
```

It basically pulls the username out of the accounts table and adds it to the friends table where they are accepted friends. I am new to joins and don't know wether I should use this LEFT (i think) join or another?

Comment: That doesn't look likea a valid chunk of MySQL to me! Is there something else in there? Can you remove it to show us just a valid MySQL query?

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: Excluding any minor syntax errors (I haven't run it), how does it look invalid?

Comment: @derobert: I don't recall any such SQL syntax as `$q = $dbc -> prepare`. Happy to be corrected, though.

Comment: It is just PDO @TomalakGeret'kal

Comment: @cgeweb87: I see. And how is PDO related to this question about a MySQL query? Can you remove this extraneous third-party technology to produce a concise and precise testcase? It should be one of the first things you do during your debugging.

Comment: No. I wasn't debugging, and my question wasn't about my code failing. The PDO is relevant as it shows the viewer of the question what the escaped mysql character is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently doing an inner join. Your query is equivalent to writing:

```
SELECT social.withID, accounts.username 
  FROM social INNER JOIN accounts ON (social.withID = accounts.id)
  WHERE social.id = ? AND friendAccept = 1
```

The difference between your query and what you'd get if you switched to a left outer join is what happens if the record doesn't exist in the right-hand table. With an inner join, if the record doesn't exist in accounts (according to the ON condition, e.g., can't find an account with that id), then no row will be returned. With a left outer join, nulls will be returned instead.

I don't know your schema, but I suspect a connection (withID) can only go to an account that exists, so the row in accounts will always exist. But let's consider a related query:

```
SELECT a.account_id, COUNT(s.withID) AS friend_count
   FROM accounts a INNER JOIN social s ON (a.account_id = s.withID)
   GROUP BY a.account_id
```

If you leave that as inner join, then people without any friends will not show in the output (because there will be no match for the ON condition). If you change it to left join, then they'll show up in the output as having zero friends. [This query may be ignoring accepted status, etc.… once again, I don't know your schema]

Comment: Thanks, this has made it alot clearer for me, yes the connection will always exist with the column withID, thanks again bud

Answer (score 0):

Looks ok to me.

Your comma usage [is equivalent to an `INNER JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html), BTW.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, explicitly show the join:

```
SELECT social.withID, accounts.username 
      FROM social inner join accounts on social.withID = accounts.id 
      WHERE social.id = ? AND friendAccept = 1
```

It won't hide the intent of your query, it will be more obvious to the developer what your intention is as opposed to having `where a.id=b.id`